# (Perl) Use of uninitialized value $_ in map

Tags: perl, initialization, export-to-csv

I am trying to export query result to CSV file using this code :

```
while (my $query_result = $query_select->fetchrow_arrayref) {       
print $fh join (',', map {s{"}{""}g; "=\"$_\"";} @$query_result), "\n";
}
```

and get these warnings :

1. Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string
2. Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)

because there is NULL value in some records.

How to replace the **undefined** value to **empty string** in the code?

Thank you.

Comment: What a horribly bad idea. Use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) instead.

Comment: @TLP: In this case I agree. But more often than not, if there are no quoted fields, a simple `print join(',', @$query_result), "\n"` is better

Comment: If you don't need to manipulate the data, then using SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE would IMO be the the most efficient approach.

Comment: @Borodin I would not say "is better", I would say "is a simpler solution".

Comment: @TLP: I wish I could remember the problems I encountered when I tried to make `Text::CSV` behave in the same way as a simple `split /,/`. The result was far from being clear, and involved tinkering with the original parser object in non-obvious ways. I will stick with `split` being *hugely better* for simple ASCII data whose fields contain no separators or quote delimiters

Comment: @Borodin I have similar experiences, for example when trying to convince Text::CSV not to add quotes. However, I do believe that it does what it does to comply with the CSV format. When you want CSV output, this module is the proper tool. When you just want a list of values, comma separated, you can just use split/join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do it, depending on when you want to do it.

1:  Within map.
Map will evaluate the entire contents of the given block, so if $_ is null, you can make it a blank string instead.

```
print $fh join (',', map {$_='' if (!defined $_); s{"}{""}g; "=\"$_\"";} @$query_result), "\n";
```

2: The approach I would take is by making sure the values aren't null when I get it from the database.  Every RDBMS that I can think of has a coalesce function that returns the first non-null value in a list.

```
SELECT coalesce(a,''),coalesce(b,''),coalesce(c+d,'')...
```

Will ensure that you won't get null values.

Comment: Nice.  Less mungy and clearer in intent than my similar approach. Your answer was not visible when I was writing mine :-\

Answer (score 7):

Don't try to hack your own version, use a proper CSV module, like [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to do this. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { 
    binary => 1,
    eol => $/, 
} );

...

$csv->print(*STDOUT, $query_result);
```

Comment: By the way there are legitimate reasons to not use Text::CSV, for instance the fact it is not a core module. And the question may arise in another context.

Comment: @fjardon: Yes. More importantly, you have to turn cartwheels to get it to do the equivalent of a simple `chomp; split /,/` or `split /\t/` if that is appropriate. It works well only when you expect quoted fields that may themselves contain escaped quotes, and then it's pretty much mandatory

Comment: @Borodin You do not have to do cartwheels. The code I provided will do that split. Since the OP is trying to handle quotes, I assume there are quotes embedded.

Comment: @TLP I think the OP is trying to handle undefined values. he even put it in **bold** and in its question title... if someone arrives here by searching for  this question he certainly wants a solution to this problem, not how to correctly parse CSV.

Comment: @fjardon, That's not a legitimate reason. If you can install code from SO, you can install code from CPAN.

Comment: @TLP: I specifically excluded this question. [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) is necessary where the fields can be quote-delimited

Comment: @ikegami Not all code from CPAN can be installed everywhere. Don't assume people are under linux or using x86. Most CPAN packages depends on other packages which in turn depends on XS, which cannot always be compiled.

Comment: @fjardon https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#blank_is_undef If someone arrives here searching for the solution to "undefined warnings", this is certainly the wrong place to look.

Comment: @fjardon, You didn't say people couldn't install Text::CSV because it wasn't portable; you said people couldn't install Text::CSV because it was on CPAN. That's not true, and the same goes for any claim that Text::CSV isn't portable.

Comment: @ikegami: Indeed, and I favour writing `use Text::CSV` in new code because it will check to see whether the pure-Perl implementation [`Text::CSV_PP`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_PP) or the C version [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_XS) is available, and choose the faster XS version if it is there

Comment: @Borodin, Personally, I prefer requiring Text::CSV_XS. I don't like the idea of silently defaulting to something slower because you forgot to install a module. Personal preference.

Comment: @ikegami This will be my last comment. 1) The question is **not answered**: *how to handle undefined values in map*. 2) I didn't talk specifically of Text::CSV. I said someone may want to not install ANY cpan packages, because it is hard to know if it won't drag the whole earth with it. And **you** said everybody **can** install **all** cpan packages. Please read yourself: *If you can install code from SO, you can install code from CPAN*.

Comment: @fjardon This question is an example of what is commonly known as [the XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Therefore his current problem is not his real problem. Handling undefined problems is pretty basic, and it would differ for each individual case how you would best handle it. Your solution, to hide the problem, is not always a good idea. Sometimes you WANT to know about undefined values.

Comment: Re "The question is not answered", This does answer the question. Your CSV is built without warning from undef values.

Comment: Re "You said everybody can install all cpan packages", I said no such thing! I simply contradicted your claim that Text::CSV not being a core module is a legitimate reason not to use it.

Comment: @TLP: Remember that the vast majority of day-to-day problems are X-Y problems. We are used to contriving our own solutions and asking for others to fulfil the individual blocks. For instance, I have asked if a taxi can take me to Leicester on Thursday. The driver doesn't expect to know that I am going there to visit my mother before I take the train to Heathrow and fly to Greece. So, if I were a novice programmer, I could be forgiven for asking for help with a small step on the way to *my own* solution. It is easy to forget that we have a privileged view of the way programming problems work

Comment: Re "how to handle undefined values in map", Same way as everywhere else: Base the result on a check of whether the value is undef or not.

Comment: @Borodin, Both Windows distros come with a C compiler, which you don't even need with AP since it provides the module in binary form. I do provide a way of requesting Text::CSV_PP in my modules that use Text::CSV_XS, but I reverse the bad default Text::CSV provides. Text::CSV_XS is the default, Text::CSV_PP must be requested.

Comment: @ikegami: I agree it's off-topic, but I'm hoping I can persuade you that the average Windows user *really cannot* install CPAN modules easily

Comment: @Borodin, If that's true, then they can't install Text::CSV_PP either. But it's not true. You're talking about the average user that can install an application. (There'd be no other reason to install a module.) You've already convinced this user to install Perl, so he should have no problem doing `cpan Module::Name` too.

Comment: @Borodin good point re: privilege.   TLP ++ ... sometimes life is an XY  problem :-\ ikegami ++ re: CPAN with ratings and curated Task collections why should even a newbie or lawyer fear the CPAN? Imagine if everyone could only build frontends with "core javascript"...

Answer (score 2):

```
say join " , ", map { s{"}{""}g; "\"$_\"" ; }  
 @{["stuff", undef, "nonsense", undef, "\""]} ;
```

Replicates your errors:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at (eval 644) line 10.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 644) line 10.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at (eval 644) line 10.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 644) line 10.
```

To fix it you could just use `map` twice to "pre-munge" the list to transform the undefs into something else:

```
say join " , ", map { s{"}{""}g; "\"$_\"" ; } (
     map { $_="NA" if (not defined $_) ; $_ } 
     @{["stuff", undef, "nonsense", undef, "\""]} ) ;
```

**output:**

```
"stuff" , "NA" , "nonsense" , "NA" , """"
```

A bit ugly (cut and pasted from [`re.pl`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL)) but you get the idea.

Speaking of "pre-munging", is there some way your `$query_select->` call could do that during the query itself?  Changing the query might avoid the problem at that level (*e.g.* with `for (@queryrow) {$_ = 'NA' unless defined};` or something).

Answer (score 1):

Why not let mysql handle it by using **SELECT .... INTO OUTFILE**

Here is an example (from the mysql documentation) that produces a file in the comma-separated values (CSV) format used by many programs:

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html

Comment: The OP didn't say which RDBMS they're using.

Answer (score 0):

**$*=$*//'';** is the same as **$*='' unless defined $*;**

```
print $fh join (',', map {$_=$_//'';s{"}{""}g; ;"=\"$_\""} @{$query_result}), "\n";
```